# Java single threaded RMI or alternative

Tags: java, rmi, rpc

The Lotus Notes Java library only runs in 32-bit JVM, and I need to call it from my 64-bit JVM app, so I wrote an RMI bridge:  The 64-bit app runs the 32-bit RMI server, and talks to the 32-bit server to make Lotus Notes calls.

Lotus Notes requires each thread (that will call any Lotus Notes functions) to call lotus.domino.NotesThread.sinitThread(); before calling any other Lotus Notes functions, and to cleanup at the very end by calling the un-init function, and these calls can be expensive.

Since RMI does not guarantee single-threaded execution, how can I pipe all the requests to a a single thread that has been initialized for Lotus Notes?  I'm open to other RPC/"bridge" methods as well (prefer to use Java).  Currently, I would have to make sure EVERY RMI function call I have defined makes sure its thread is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [single thread executor service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29), and each time you want to call a lotus notes method, submit a task to the executor, get the returned Future, and get the result of the method call from the Future.

For example, to call the method `Bar getFoo()`, you would use the following code:

```
Callable<Bar> getFoo = new Callable<Bar>() {
    @Override
    public Bar call() {
        return lotuNotes.getFoo();
    }
};
Future<Bar> future = executor.submit(getFoo);
return future.get();
```

Comment: I'm posting the final code I used below (can't post code here easily)

Answer (score 0):

getName() is a simple example, so each code gets this kind of treatment (which bloats the code tremendously, but it works!)

```
    @Override
    public String getName() throws RemoteException, NotesException {
        java.util.concurrent.Callable<String> callableRoutine =
                new java.util.concurrent.Callable<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public String call() throws java.rmi.RemoteException, NotesException {
                        return lnView.getName();
                    }
                };
        try {
            return executor.submit(callableRoutine).get();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            handleExceptions(ex);
            return null; // not used
        }
    }


/**
 * Handle exceptions from serializing to a thread.
 *
 * This routine always throws an exception, does not return normally.
 *
 * @param ex
 * @throws java.rmi.RemoteException
 * @throws NotesException
 */
private void handleExceptions(Throwable ex) throws java.rmi.RemoteException, NotesException {
    if (ex instanceof ExecutionException) {
        Throwable t = ex.getCause();
        if (t instanceof java.rmi.RemoteException) {
            throw (java.rmi.RemoteException) ex.getCause();
        } else if (t instanceof NotesException) {
            throw (NotesException) ex.getCause();
        } else {
            throw new NotesException(LnRemote.lnErrorRmi, utMisc.getExceptionMessageClean(t), t);
        }
    } else {
        throw new NotesException(LnRemote.lnErrorRmi, utMisc.getExceptionMessageClean(ex), ex);
    }
}
```